# Rails 3 Open Word Documents Inline

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ms-word, doc

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is it possible to display an RTF file inside a web page using PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/678192/is-it-possible-to-display-an-rtf-file-inside-a-web-page-using-php)

I would like to display .doc files inline on page.
I try to use send_file method in my controller action:

```
    mime_types = {
        :doc => 'application/msword',
        :docx => 'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document',
        :pdf => 'application/pdf',
        :rtf => 'application/rtf',
        :jpg => 'image/jpeg',
        :tiff => 'image/tiff'
    }

    send_file 'c:/sites/efiling2/test.rtf', 
        :filename => '2', 
        :type => mime_types[:doc], 
        :disposition => 'inline'
```

For pdf files it works, but for doc files browser asks me to open file in Word or to save it on dics.

**Is it possible to open doc files inline on page?**

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/678192/is-it-possible-to-display-an-rtf-file-inside-a-web-page-using-php

Answer (score 0):

the problem is that your browser is not able to view the word doc file thats why its offering you to save it. I would suggest you look into some HTML document viewers. take a look at http://www.documentcloud.org/opensource