# Classic Rich Text Format in a webpage

Tags: javascript, html, widget, editor, rtf

I am trying to build a webpage in which a user can edit a Rich Text that comes from an RTF blob.

RTF is saved with ["Classic format"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rich_Text_Format), so for example the content of the blob is like this:

```
{\rtf\ansi\deff0{\fonttbl{\f0\froman Tms Rmn;}{\f1\fdecor 
Symbol;}{\f2\fswiss Helv;}}{\colortbl;\red0\green0\blue0;
\red0\green0\blue255;\red0\green255\blue255;\red0\green255\
blue0;\red255\green0\blue255;\red255\green0\blue0;\red255\
green255\blue0;\red255\green255\blue255;}{\stylesheet{\fs20 \snext0Normal;}}{\info{\author John Doe}
{\creatim\yr1990\mo7\dy30\hr10\min48}{\version1}{\edmins0}
{\nofpages1}{\nofwords0}{\nofchars0}{\vern8351}}\widoctrl\ftnbj \sectd\linex0\endnhere \pard\plain \fs20 This is plain text.\par}
```

All the javascript widgets I find online are HTML editors, so one solution is convert from and to HTML to close the loop, even if in this way I will lose some information in the process. This will work for sure.

Anyway since i need in the short term to maintain the RTF format i would prefer to edit RTF directly in the browser, any idea on how to do?

In future I plan to upgrade the edit content from RTF to HTML so any [TinyMCE](https://www.tiny.cloud/)-like editor will work fine.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After doing further research all i found is [this javascript library](https://github.com/tbluemel/rtf.js) that allows only to display RTF.

It seems there is a "gap in the market": all widgets focus on HTML.

[This PHP related SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/678192/is-it-possible-to-display-an-rtf-file-inside-a-web-page-using-php) is somehow a duplicate of my question.